# How to change value of display property after it has been set to display: none

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

First of all sorry if the question title is confusing, I couldn't figure out how else to put it.
I am working on a React application. I am supposed to make a custom `Alert` component for my application which I did. I also put a button to dismiss the alert. Following is my alert component.

**Alert Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles.css';
const Alert = ({ text, type }) => {
    function closeAlert(event) {
        event.target.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    }

    return ( 
        <div className = "alert" id = { type }>
        <span className = "closebtn" onClick = { closeAlert }>& times;</span> 
            { text } </div>
    );
};
export default Alert;
```

So my issue is something like this:
When I click the Login button and the user has entered invalid credentials, I display an `error alert`. I dismiss the alert by clicking the `&times` sign. Then I click Login a second time, again with wrong credentials. But this time the alert doesn't show up because I did `display: none` on the previous click. Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the status of the Alert in the parent component like in the following example.

You can then show or not the `Alert` component with `{ showAlert && <Alert/> }`

```js
const Alert = ({ text, type, closeAlert }) => {
    return ( 
        <div className = "alert" id = { type }>
          <span className = "closebtn" onClick = { closeAlert }>& times;</span> 
          { text } 
        </div>
    );
};

class Hello extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showAlert: false
  };
  
  closeAlert = () => this.setState({ showAlert: false });
  showAlert = () => this.setState({ showAlert: true });
  
  render() {
    const { showAlert } = this.state;
    return 
      (<div>
        <button onClick={this.showAlert}>Show</button>
        { showAlert && <Alert text="ERROR" type="error" closeAlert={this.closeAlert}/> }
      </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: I actually  wanted to avoid writing the code for showing/hiding the alert in my container. But for now I have done this and it works. So I'll go ahead and accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you could do this

```js
if(event.target.parentElement.style.display == 'none'){
    event.target.parentElement.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    event.target.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Just check its display and put to oposite of it.

Hope it helped

Comment: It doesn't work. I had also tried putting an style property for the Alert div, where I set `display: block` but that didn't work either.